# org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session

Tags: appium

I am trying to automate mobile web automation test cases on android phone but I am getting the below error:-

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 3.16.0-77-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 12 milliseconds
```

Please see the below code snippet:

```
ChromeOptions c=new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

dc.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
dc.setCapability("appium-version", "1.6.0");
dc.setCapability("deviceName", "4d00b83ed4f7426f");
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0.1");
dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
dc.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, c);

dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
dc.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.document.ChromeLauncherActivity");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In Appium server logs I am getting below error:

```
[ADB] Error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13) at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:441:9) at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runti‌​me/regenerator/runti‌​me.js:67:40) at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runti‌​me/regenerator/runti‌​me.js:315:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error comes up when:

1. Appium Server is not running
2. Connection with the Appium server is lost for any reason
3. Appium server misconfigured.

Make sure you have your Appium GUI app open and have a look at its console when the execution starts. You should see that the server is at least is up and getting your request. The from the log, try to see why it fails. If there is no response in Appium console and it just stays unchanged, that means that your configuration is wrong. Perhaps you are using an incorrect port.

Comment: I am getting below error in Appium server logs :-
[ADB] Error: Unable to get pids for uiautomator. Orginial error: this.shell(...).trim is not a function
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (lib/logger.js:60:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (lib/tools/adb-commands.js:441:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)

Comment: @DivyaBahl Did you try googling that?